# Routing error 'no POST route for /x/new' on scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried this on a dozen fresh projects and seen the same problem each time, I don't understand why.

1. `rails new project_name`
2. `cd project_name`, `rails generate scaffold book`
3. In /db/migrate/xxxxxx_create_book, add the lines `t.integer :year`, `t.text :title`
4. `rake db:migrate`
5. `rails s -d`
6. Go to localhost/books, see a valid list, try to create a book, get the error "No route for POST books/new".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your routes.rb?

Comment: @Mandeep the only route in routes.db is "resources :books".

Comment: Please post the `controller code` along the `form code` which is used to create a new book.

Comment: http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/wann_sollte_man_scaffold_benutzen.html

Comment: @Pavan [Controller](http://bpaste.net/show/nVKBhvafGl9cPGlW6gYU/), [new.html.erb](http://bpaste.net/show/84OO7rbBzsymrbJ5IRgI/)

Comment: Can you post your `_form.html.erb`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change anything in the views?

Possible cause for this is that in your books/index.html.erb you changed the new_book link to something like :

```
<%= link_to 'New Book', new_book_path, method: :post %>
```

from

```
<%= link_to 'New Book', new_book_path %>
```

When you look at routes (rake routes) you will see:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
new_book GET    /books/new(.:format)      books#new
```

This means that only GET action is allowed to access books#new.

Cheers!

Comment: I didn't modify any files outside of the steps outlined above. None of the files in the 'views' folder have the word `post` mentioned anywhere.